# Laravel user auth check "enabled" column as well as email and password

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('/start')->withErrors($validator);
        } else {
            if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
            {
                echo 'success';
            }
        }
```

There is another column in my users table called enabled. This needs to equal 1 for the user attempting to log in, otherwise they should be sent back to the log in screen with a message telling them that the account is disabled.

How can I achieve this?

---

```
$details = array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']);
    if (Auth::user()->enabled) {
        if(Auth::attempt($details)) {
            echo 'success';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'disabled!';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure somebody will give you an "extend it this way" answer, but the easiest by far is to just add another condition to the code. Also, you don't need to wrap the login attempt within an else, since the first if condition returns if it triggers. See the below example.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('/start')->withErrors($validator);
}

$details = array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']);
if (Auth::attempt($details) && Auth::user()->enabled) {
    echo 'success';
}
```

Edit: As Lukas Geiter pointed out, please note that the user will still be logged in - you'll have to manually log them out as well if applicable. This resolves that issue:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('/start')->withErrors($validator);
}

$details = array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']);
if (Auth::attempt($details)) {
    if (!Auth::user()->enabled) {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('/your-login-screen-with-some-message');
    }
    echo 'success';
}
```

I should also mention that you could actually just add `'enabled' => 1` to the credentials, but then you would not be able to distinguish disabled users from incorrect credentials.

Comment: I like this simple approach but you have to either, log out if the user is not enabled or use `Auth::check()` and afterwards `Auth::login()`. Now if the use is not enabled he will still be logged in!

Comment: Does my edit solve that issue? As it checks to see if the account is disabled first before logging the user in.

Comment: No, the ``Auth::attempt()`` logs the user in, so you can't do ``Auth::user()`` until after the attempt. I'll edit in how you could do instead.

Comment: Problem with this approach is later you may want another login route (e.g. expose functionality as an API) then you will have to duplicate the authentication logic, thus violating DRY. Good method for small, throw-away projects though.

Comment: @ChrisHarrison Yes, absolutely. Like I noted, it's just the easiest solution to the problem - not necessarily the smartest one.